# Coredata relationship issue

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm facing a weird issue with my core data. I've the following relationship [image]

A contact can belong to one category and a category can have multiple contacts. I'd like to access my category in the contact when creating my contact. 
Is my relationship correct ?

I'm receiving the following error "cannot assign a value of type 'String!' to a value of type 'Category'" in this field:
    newContact.category = categoryField.text

That's how I tried to access my category field:

```
// MARK: - Properties
    var contact: Contact?   

func createCategory() {
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Category", inManagedObjectContext: context!)
        let category = Category(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
        let index = pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(0)
        let color = categoryColor[index]

            category.name = name.text
            category.descript = descriptionField.text
            category.color = color
            println(category.name)
            context?.save(nil)
        name.text = ""
        descriptionField.text = ""
    }

     func createNewContact() {
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Contact", inManagedObjectContext: context!)
            let newContact = Contact(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
                newContact.name = nameField.text
                newContact.email = emailField.text
                newContact.phone = phoneField.text
                newContact.category = categoryField.text
                newContact.photo = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageHolder.image, 1)

            var error: NSError?

            context?.save(&error)
    }

And that's how my entities look like: 

    @objc (Contact)
    class Contact: NSManagedObject {

        @NSManaged var email: String
        @NSManaged var name: String
        @NSManaged var phone: String
        @NSManaged var photo: NSData
        @NSManaged var category: Category

    }
```

and

```
@objc (Category)
class Category: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var color: AnyObject
    @NSManaged var descript: String!
    @NSManaged var name: String!
    @NSManaged var contact: NSOrderedSet

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `category` property of a `Contact` object is a `Category` object.  But you are trying to set it to be a String (`categoryField.text`).  You probably want to use a `Category` object whose `name` is equal to `categoryField.text`.

You could create one:

```
    let categoryEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Category", inManagedObjectContext: context!)
    let newCategory = Category(entity: categoryEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
    newCategory.name = categoryField.text
    // set the other properties for the Category as necessary
    // then assign the relationship
    newContact.category = newCategory
```

But you might already have created a `Category` with that `name`.  So the usual approach would be to search for a Category with the right `name`, use that if it exists, or create a new Category if not:

```
    let categoryEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Category", inManagedObjectContext: context!)
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
    fetchRequest.entity = categoryEntity!
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"name == %@",categoryField.text)
    let fetchResults = try? context!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
    if let results = fetchResults {
        var requiredCategory : Category
        if (results.count > 0) {
            requiredCategory = results[0] as! Category
        } else {
            requiredCategory = Category(entity: categoryEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context!)
            requiredCategory.name = categoryField.text
            // set the other properties for the Category as necessary
        }
        newContact.category = requiredCategory
    }
```

Comment: do you mind going to a private chat, i'm very new into swift and ios, will need to ask some few questions

Comment: @congolesedevelopper Happy to go to chat.

Comment: @congolesedevelopper I've created a [chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90769/discussion-of-coredata-relationships).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in your error:

> Cannot assign a value of type 'String!' to a value of type 'Category'

The error is saying, that your `category` property in `Contact` class is defined to hold `Category` type object rather than an instance of `NSString`.

So you need to assign an object of type `Category`, something like this:

Create new category, or get an existing category by any means, here we'll create new category and assign that to the contact.

```
let catEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Category", inManagedObjectContext: context!)
let category = Category(entity: catEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
category.name = categoryField.text // get the name from field and set to category property
category.color = someColor //assign your required color
```

Now assign that to your category property in Contact, like this:

```
newContact.category = category
```

Comment: That's why I wrote that you can create new category or get an existing category by any means, ie through `NSFetchRequest` into your database, or already fetched category. I wrote details of creating the new category only, the idea was to give you a pointer where you need todo the correct things.